# How to retrieve the number of adults selected on a travel website with .getText() not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am practicing Selenium Webdriver using Java on the following website:
https://www.easyjet.com/en

I am trying to increase the number of Adults selected until 3 has been selected. Here is my code:

```
package d_practise;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class easyjetMenu5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\Drivers\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.easyjet.com/en");

        WebElement adultCount = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='Adults']"));
        String count = adultCount.getText();

        while(!count.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[passenger-type='Adults'] [alt='Add one passenger\\.']")).click();
        }

    }

};
```

Here is an image of the number value I am trying to retrieve. Once I am able to get this number I can use it in the while loop to stop incrementing the number of adults selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\Drivers\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

         driver.get("https://www.easyjet.com/en");
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'Adults')]/following-sibling::button"))));


      int numberOfAdults=3;

            for (int i = 2; i <=numberOfAdults ; i++) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'Adults')]/following-sibling::button")).click();

            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't really do what I am trying to achieve. This code is similar to saying click the + button 3 times when what I am after is retrieving the value and getting my code to stop incrementing when the target value has been reached.